# Hyperbolic circles, horocycles and hypercycles

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

How do you write a formula for Hyperbolic circles, horocycles and hypercycles in Normal form give a point of rotation, or translation?

Specifically,

- a hyperbolic rotation (hyperbolic circle) about the point 1/2
- A parallel displacement (horocycle) about the ideal point -1
- A hyperbolic translation (hypercycle) from -i to i

I'm pretty confused.

I think Normal form is:

(Tz-p)/(Tz-q)=λ (z-p)/(z-q)

If the problem I am working didn't suggest using normal form I would think I could write the equation of a cycle, for the first two, with the center as the point of rotation.

Comment: In which model?

Comment: That is about how clueless I am :D . We are studying the Hyperbolic plane.   Is that what you mean about model?

Comment: You are using complex numbers in your question, and the hyperbolic plane has more models, embedded into Euclidean plane, i.e. into $\Bbb C$. By $-1$ being ideal, it seems you are using one of the disk models. Also, what is a '*normal form*' here?

Comment: Yes, I believe it is the Poincare Disk Model.

Comment: (Tz-p)/(Tz-q)=λ (z-p)/(z-q) .  Is the the normal form of a M¨obius transformation with two fixed points